Encoding error while running Electron tutorial in Windows 10
I'm starting the intro tutorial for Electron in VS Code on Windows 10:
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-first-app.
main.js
console.log('Hello from Electron ')


Instead of the expected output: Hello from Electron ,
I'm seeing Hello from Electron ≡ƒæï
I assume I'm having an encoding error. I checked that VS Code is set to UTF-8. I also tried several different fonts in the Powershell window I'm using.
EDIT: How do I get the expected output?

You're not asking a question. In any case, if you want to ask how to fix some code, you'd have to extract a [mcve] and provide that along with both expected and actual output.

Thanks for checking. sorry thought the issue was somewhat self explanatory given it's directly from the Tutorial and works up until the output issue.
